# Deploying flask application factory on apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm not having any luck getting this to work.

my run.py file which works fine looks like this :

```
from dpc import create_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app("config.py")

    app.run("0.0.0.0",debug=True,port=666,threaded=True)
```

my application factory in __init__.py looks like this:

```
def create_app(config_filename):
    app = CustomFlask(__name__)
    from dpc import mongo_models
    app.config.from_pyfile(config_filename)
    app.register_blueprint(retrieve, url_prefix="/retrieve")
    return app
```

and my wsgi file looks like this:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/dpc')

from dpc import create_app
app = create_app("config.py")
```

my httpd.conf file has this:

```
<VirtualHost *:666>
    ServerName DPC

    WSGIScriptAlias / C:/dpc/dpc/dpc.wsgi

    <Directory C:\dpc >
        Options All
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have a non application factory flask app running fine on Apache and have merrily for years, but this one gives me no errors and returns nothing.  I've been trying various changes and searching for a solution for the last few hours to no avail.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a relative pathname for the config file in:

```
app = create_app("config.py")
```

It has to be an absolute path.

Read:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#application-working-directory

If you are getting back empty respones or it hangs, also try setting:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Read:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api

The WSGI application entry point in the WSGI script file should also be set as:

```
application = create_app("c:/dpc/dpc/config.py")
```

In other words, `application` and not `app`. This is because mod_wsgi looks for `application`. If not done, you would get back 404 response, but also possibly an error in the Apache error logs as well.

Comment: Hmmmm, neither change has had an effect.  I changed config.py to c:\dpc\dpc\config.py.  I'll remove the reliance on the config.py part altogether just to see if it has an impact.

Comment: How exactly in the code did you add the path? You cannot use backslashes in paths unless you use a raw string. Better to use forward slashes.

Comment: See further fix around name of WSGI application object. Make sure you are checking Apache error logs. Add ``LogLevel info`` to Apache configuration and then check error logs. Should show then if mod_wsgi gets request and loads WSGI script when request arrives.

Comment: yep nothings showing up in the error logs at all, its very weird.  I did indeed use a raw string.

Comment: arrrgh! found the problem, I hadn't told the apache server to listen on the new port.  So stupid.  Thanks for your help!  What you've provided is very useful.